# Android: re-use fragment and issue with view

Tags: android, fragment

I have a fragment to show user profile. Whenever call this, i pass an user Id to. Then in onCreateView, i call service to get user profile with the Id then update the GUI when finish.

By desgin, in my profile there is a button that open an activity to show all the post i liked. Each post had an avatar (of author) and title. When click on the avatar, i have to show the author profile.

And, my problem is showed as the image below:

[image]

When i viewing my profile, i click on the button "liked post" to open the list of post i liked. Then i click on author avatar to view author profile.

At author profile screeen, i press back to go back to the post list. Again, i press back one more time to go back to my profile.

At here (on resume i don't reload/re-get user profile because it affect when i startActivityForResult (camera, galary) to change profile image), you can see that i'm on my profile but the value on view is from the last one (From User 3 - in red color).

Based on the log, the profile was not destroy from begin to end. It seem only the view inside.

My question is: do you have any suggestions for solve it without re-get profile user when resume. Or any other way to re-use profile fragment without this issue?

**UPDATE (18/8/2015)**

My tmp solution is add a flag to known if the app resume as normal or resume by startActivityForResult. If it resume as normal then reload and else.

Comment: What did you use to model those screens? That looks really good.

Comment: If Theyre all fragment you can just do in fragmenttransaction.addToBackStack("AnyTag");

Comment: is post list an activity that is different from main activity?

Comment: Eltz: yes, it is an activity different from Main activity.

Comment: @hitch.united: i used draw.io :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to sure that you re-use profile fragment by only one instance and just change the data shown when re-use, if it is, you should have a variable to record your previous shown data and update data when click back. If you have different instances of profile fragment,i don't know the way to help you without codes.

Comment: I already think about it. But the diagram just show a part. In some case, user can go to profile -> view post list -> view author profile -> view post list (that have other user not author only) -> view author profile....  So, it become complex when save the previous data.

Comment: so you can use different instance of profile fragments, it has some questions?

Comment: i'm not really understand what you mean, but now i just new fragment not use the same instance.